I use Xubuntu, what is the path command needed to access a folder shared by another Xubuntu user on the same pc?
I followed the suggestion found on this site (link below), which seems to answer my question. However, when the other user tries to access the shared folder on my Desktop, from his Desktop he gets a permission denied error. The user is in the Sudo group but I want him to avoid using root if at all possible.
How to allow folder permission for another user in Linux?
The above explains that a 'data' folder, the contents of which should be copied to the shared folder, is not necessary. I therefore created a folder on my Desktop 'SHARED' and then followed the instructions.


I therefore created a folder on my Desktop 'SHARED' and then followed the instructions.

The path is exactly as you see it. Your problem is not with the path, but most likely that the other user doesn't have access to the parent directory – they were only granted access to /home/you/Desktop/SHARED but not given any access to /home/you/Desktop, nor to /home/you overall. This was already explained in the first paragraph of the top answer within the linked thread, and is the reason why placing the shared directory elsewhere (such as /data) was recommended.
If you want the shared folder to remain inside your home directory, then you must give the other user +x permission to both your home directory and your Desktop directory. This would allow them to access anything that's been made readable by them (but only as long as they know the path, because without +r they cannot list files). Giving others +x access would be very similar to how it works on Windows, where +x on folders is implicitly granted anyway.
